# Textarea inset box-shadow now showing up on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

Box shadow is working fine for input and select fields. On desktop, textarea box shadow is working fine too. Even when I resize the window to mobile size. But when I check the site on Safari or Chrome on my iPhone, the box shadow does not show up for the textarea. Input and select fields show up fine on mobile. [Here is the link to the page.](https://benhambrothers.com/speaker-request/) How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I needed to put -webkit-appearance: none; in the CSS rules for the textarea.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using '-webkit-box-shadow'?
Its required for Safari I think.
(https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/)

Edit: Maybe try just clearing cache for the site. The css files will refresh.

Comment: The answer doesn't necessarily provide solution to the question